# jQuery Toggle/cycle through 3 state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button, which i need to run through 3 state. eg: Mute, On and Off

```
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- define mute/on/off styles -->
     <style type="text/css">
      .mute{ background:gray }
      .on  { background:green }
      .off { background:red }
     </style>

     <!-- define the toggle/cycle function -->
     <script language="javascript">
        function toggleState(item){
        if(item.className == "mute") {
              item.className="on";
           } else if(item.className == "on") {
              item.className="off";
           } else {
              item.className="mute";
           }
        }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <!-- call 'toggleState' whenever clicked -->
     <input type="button" id="btn" value="button" class="mute" onclick="toggleState(this)" />
  </body>
</html>
```

How can i cycle through this using jQuery rather using plain JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.is('.mute')) {
            $this.toggleClass("mute on");
        } else if($this.is('.on')) {
            $this.toggleClass("on off");
        } else if($this.is('.off')) {
            $this.toggleClass("off mute");
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ehZhg/)

Comment: Though @pktangyue code looks super cool (+1) but this and SudipPal's code gives me flexibility to add more lines of code easily to the selected state, Thanks.

Comment: @ArunPJohny  if user has one more state 'open', each line has to update & less readability with if ..else if ..

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
var classNames = ['mute','on','off'];
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass(function (i, className, b) {
        var index = (classNames.indexOf(className) + 1) % classNames.length;
        $(this).removeClass(className);
        return classNames[index];
    });
});
```

In this code, `className` is the old class. Then get the new class through `classNames` array, then return it.

And before return, the old class should be removed.

And with this method, you can easily expand 3 to **any larger number**.

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/f3qR3/2/

---

**Another situation**

If there are other classes in the element, you can use the following code, but it is more complicated.

```
var classNames = ['mute', 'on', 'off'];
$('div').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass(function (i, className, b) {
        var ret_index;
        $.each(classNames, function (index, value) {
            if ($this.hasClass(value)) {
                ret_index = (index + 1) % classNames.length;
            }
        });
        $this.removeClass(classNames.join(' '));
        return classNames[ret_index];
    });
});
```

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/f3qR3/4/

Comment: can you please explain this line `var index = (classNames.indexOf(className) + 1) % classNames.length;`? why are you `% classNames.length' ?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy it make sure the `index` is less than `classNames.length`, and can get a correct element.

Comment: I am a bit confused i don't understand how it return the correct index always :) whenever the number grow :)

Comment: @AhmadAlfy the `className` changes every time, so the `index` changes. You can print it to look.

Comment: this will fail the moment another class is added to the element

Comment: Great example.  I just replaced changed the css to `background-image` and it was exactly what I was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/leisenstein/eU6Ln/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btn").click(function(
var this=$(this);
if(this.hasClass('mute')) {
              this.removeClass("mute").addClass("on");
           } else if(this.hasClass('on')) {
              this.removeClass("on").addClass("off");
           } else {
              this.removeClass("off").addClass("mute");
           }
        }
});
```

You don't need to add any onclick function, just placed it under jquery ready() function.

Answer (score 1):

try this without using if and else ..

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function(){    

    var statemp = { mute: 'on', on: 'off', off :'mute' };

    var toggle = $(this).attr('class')
          .split(' ')
          // Requires JavaScript 1.6
          .map( function( cls ) {
              return statemp[ cls ] || cls ;
          })
          .join(' ');     

    $(this).attr('class','').addClass( toggle );   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterme(val){
if (val == 1){
   $('#RangeFilter').removeClass('rangeAll').removeClass('rangePassive').addClass('rangeActive');
   $("span").text("Active");
} 
else if (val == 2)
{ 
  $('#RangeFilter').removeClass('rangeActive').removeClass('rangePassive').addClass('rangeAll');
  $("span").text("All");
} 
else if(val==3){       
  $('#RangeFilter').removeClass('rangeAll').removeClass('rangeActive').addClass('rangePassive');
  $("span").text("Passive");
}
}
 <p class="range-field" style=" width:60px">
 <input type="range" id="RangeFilter" name="points" onchange="filterme(this.value);" min="1" class="rangeAll" max="3" value="2">
 </p>
<span>All</span>
```